# Very slow updates using LocatorPane

Tags: coordinate-transformation, eventhandler

Making an app for conic sections I need that when point ptA is moved, point ptB shifts the same distance and in the same direction of ptA (i.e. a translation). This is the (simplified) code.

[image]

```
Manipulate[ LocatorPane[Dynamic[{ptA, ptB}, 
                        (ptA=#[[1]]; ptB=#[[2]];
                          (* If ptA is moved*)
                          If[ptA!=ptA0, ptB= ptA-ptA0 + ptB; ptA0=ptA]
                         )&], 
Graphics[{ }, Axes->True, PlotRange-> 4]],
Initialization:>{  ptA0={0,0}; ptA={0,0}; ptB={1,0} },
]
```

On slow machines, when dragging ptA, point ptB doesn't update sufficiently fast. I have 2 questions: If I use Event Handler, does the performance improve? And how can I implement it?

Comment: The posted code has severe syntax errors. As it stands, I do not think the intent of the broken code is clear enough to for anyone to work with it.

Comment: I lost interest in this question because I guess the problem is actually a hardware problem.
By the way, the question is very clear and nobody sees any syntax error.

Comment: I've improved the performance code by using  CurrentValue["CurrentLocatorPaneThumb"] to know which locator is moving, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? I cannot really test if it is more smooth on your slow system since the original code you provided already ran pretty well on my laptop, but I think this should be a bit more optimized:

```
DynamicModule[{ptA = {0, 0}, ptB = {1, 0}},
  Graphics[{
    Locator[
      Dynamic[
        ptA,
        (
         ptB = ptB +  # - ptA;
         ptA = #
        ) &
      ]
    ],
    Locator[Dynamic[ptB]]},
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 4
  ]
]
```

*edit*

Here's a toy implementation of a locatorpane using `EventHandler`:

```
DynamicModule[{ptA = {0, 0}, ptB = {1, 1}},
  EventHandler[
    Graphics[{Point[{Dynamic[ptA], Dynamic[ptB]}]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}],
    {
      "MouseClicked" :> If[
        {ptA} === Nearest[{ptA, ptB}, MousePosition["Graphics"]],
        ptA = MousePosition["Graphics"],
        ptB = MousePosition["Graphics"]
      ],
      "MouseDragged" :> If[
        {ptA} === Nearest[{ptA, ptB}, MousePosition["Graphics"]],
        ptA = MousePosition["Graphics"],
        ptB = MousePosition["Graphics"]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use Locator in Graphics, the performance doesn't improve

Comment: Ok, good to know. To be fair, I don't expect you'll get much of an efficiency boost from trying other methods like EventHandlers. The only other optimization I can come up with is to keep `ptB` fixed while dragging `ptA` and then only updating `ptB` when you release the locator: `DynamicModule[{ptA = {0, 0}, ptB = {1, 0}, ptA0}, 
 Graphics[{Locator[
    Dynamic[ptA, {(ptA0 = ptA = #) &, (ptA = #) &, (ptB = 
         ptB + # - ptA0;
        ptA = #) &}]], Locator[Dynamic[ptB]]}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 4]]`

Comment: it seems weird, but if we use Locator Pane we get "better performance" than Locator.  That was the reason that  I thought that eventHandler could be better. Of course, in a regular fast machines, there is no problems. Anyway, in the few "slow machines"  we have, only we have to take care and dragging not so fast. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's strange; I wouldn't have expected `LocatorPane` to be faster. If you're still interested, I rolled a toy example of a custom locatorpane using `EventHandler` and I will add it to my answer. Maybe it's of use to you.

Comment: Fine fine!! I would like to see it. Ah ok, I already saw it

Comment: I guess the problem is actually a hardware problem